# call function based on string android

Tags: java, android, function

i have class something like this

```
class MClass
{
private int mem1,mem2,mem3.......;
public int getmem1()
{
return mem1;
}
public int getmem2()
{
return mem2;
}

......
```

Now I want something like this :

```
public int getAttr(String attr)
{
if (attr=="mem1")
return mem1;
elseif (attr=="mem2")
return mem2;
.....
```

How do I implement getAttr for 1000s of attr ?

Please don't ask me to make mem as array.. that is not possible due to other parts of program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use reflection. [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

This will allow you to call any public method at runtime using the name of the method as a String.

```
Class c = Class.forName("MyClass");
Method m = c.getMethod("get"+arg);
return (Integer) m.invoke(this);
```

Comment: Then he has to define thousands of getXXX methods, don't think this will work as a solution

Comment: I am okay with defining those, i don't want to change the data type in my class as I mentioned.. John answered perfectly .. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create a `Map<String, Integer> attrMap` and do

```
public int getAttr(String attr) {
    return attrMap.get(attr);
}
```

Comment: I know it's late but if I had to guess the downvote came because the the question requested a solution without an array (HashTable, Map, Disctionary).

Answer (score 1):

You create a `Map<String,Object>`. As key you use the attr, as value the values.

```
class MyCall {

    private final Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public Object getAttr(String attr) {

        return map.get(attr);

    }
}
```

If the values will be always integers, then you can replace the generic parameter `Object` with `Integer`.

```
public int getAttr(String attr)  {

   if(map.contains(attr)) {
    return map.get(attr).intValue();
   } else {
    reutrn ERROR_CODE; //As error or throw exception
   }
}
```

Comment: @Vash, for the same reason as `aioobe` above, you supplied an answer which required an array - the question clearly requested you not do that.