# android reflection in enhanced for loop

Tags: android, reflection

I know some things about reflection because i read this post: [call function based on string android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483721/call-function-based-on-string-android)

```
Class c = Class.forName("MyClass");
Method m = c.getMethod("get"+arg);
return (Integer) m.invoke(this);
```

I am using an enhanced for loop like this:

```
int check = 0,check2=0;
        for(PostValue post : helper.posts)
        {
                          //Name method with a String 
            if(category.equals(post.getMethodFromStringHere()))
            {
                check++;
            }
        }
```

so what I want is that I can get the method from a string in the if above.

Thanks in advance.

If you need more information you can ask,

EDIT:

```
try {
        int check = 0,check2=0;
        Class<?> postValueClass = Class.forName("PackageName.PostValue");
        Method m = postValueClass.getMethod("get"+category);
        for(PostValue post : helper.posts)
        {
            String response;
            response = (String) m.invoke(post);

            if(category.equals(response))
            {
                check++;
            }
```

Comment: cannot understand anything from your post

Comment: in the if I want to have the method at post.Methodhere that i can use a String to name the method.

Comment: i think you should read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that would do the job. i haven't tested it !! You might need to cast some objects.

```
Class postValueClass = Class.forName("PostValue");
Method getMethodFromStringHereMethod = postValueClass.getMethod("getMethodFromStringHere");

int check = 0;
int check2 = 0;
for(PostValue post : helper.posts)
{
  Boolean response = (Boolean) getMethodFromStringHereMethod.invoke(post);
  if (response.getBooleanValue())
  {
    check ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but the forname can not find my class the class is in another package i dont know if it has anything to do with it but it does not find the class.

Comment: Thanks for the Help it works now i will post the working one in my post